# Thymeleaf/jQuery fraction

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

I've 3 ingredients and I want to display their amount as a fraction if It's a double. For instance, if it's 1.4 then It would display as 1/4. It works fine, but for some reason it displays all the ingredients on the first line, then on the second it display with 1 less ingredient, third 2, and so on. I want to display each on 1 line.

Is this possible to do with just Thymeleaf? Or how would I stop it from displaying all the ingredients on the first line, then again on the second?

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li class="ingredient-display" th:each="ingredient : ${recipe.ingredients}">
    <script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var amount = [[${ingredient.getAmount()}]];
    var ingredient_name = [[${ingredient.ingredientName}]];
    var ingredient_unit_of_measure = [[${ingredient.unitOfMeasure.unitName}]];  
    var parts = amount.toString().split(".");
    if(amount === +amount && amount !== (amount|0)) {
      if(parts[0] == 1 || parts[0] == 2){
          $(".ingredient-display").append("&frac" + parts[0] + "" + parts[1] + "; " + ingredient_unit_of_measure + " " + ingredient_name);      
        } 
    } else {
      $(".ingredient-display").append(amount + " "+ ingredient_unit_of_measure + " " + ingredient_name);
    }
    /*]]>*/ 
    </script>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to do it, but for some reason HTML doesn't display `&frac17` or `&frac19`. Here is the code if someone will bump into the same problem

```
<ol class="list">
 <li class="ingredient-display" th:each="ingredient, iter : ${recipe.ingredients}">
  <script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var amount = [[${ingredient.getAmount()}]];
    var ingredient_name = [[${ingredient.ingredientName}]];
    var ingredient_unit_of_measure = [[${ingredient.unitOfMeasure.unitName}]];
    var i = [[${iter.index}]];

    var parts = amount.toString().split(".");
    var _list = "<li class='list-list"+i+"'>&frac"+parts[0]+parts[1]+";" + " "+ingredient_unit_of_measure+" "+ingredient_name+"</li>";
    if(amount === +amount && amount !== (amount|0)) {
      if(parts[0] != 0 || parts[1] != 7 || parts[1] != 9){
        $(".list").append(_list);
      } 
    }else{
     var list = "<li class='list-list"+i+"'></li>";
    $(".list").append(list);
    $(".list-list"+i).append(amount + " "+ ingredient_unit_of_measure + " " + ingredient_name);
    }
    /*]]>*/ 
  </script>
 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Okay apparently It's better if we use ``<sup>nr</sup>&frasl;<sub>nr</sub>`` instead of ``&frac[nr][nr]`` since it can display any number